# Populate DropDown with JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, xhtml, javabeans, bootsfaces

```
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = new HashMap<String,
Map<String, String>>();
private String type;

private Map<String, String> types;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    formSchema = new JSONObject();
    types = new HashMap<String, String>();
    types.put("name", "name");
    types.put("address", "address");
    types.put("number", "Number");

}

public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getData() {
    return data;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Map<String, String> getTypes() {
    return types;
}
```

This is my code for DropDown menu.

I am passing the values in xhtml as-

```
<b:selectOneMenu id="type" value="#{dropdownView.type}"
                style="width:150px">

        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select type" itemValue=""
                    noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{dropdownView.types}" />
            </b:selectOneMenu>
```

This is working fine with hardcoded values but I need to populate the DropDown Menu with JSON schema.

I am just a beginner.Can anyone please assist me regarding how to send Json values(for example- name,address and number) to Dropdown Menu and display the values in Dropdown.Any Help would be appreciated.
Thankyou in advance.

Sending json format as an example -

{"form":{"name":"abc","id":"number","date":"true","comment":"largeText"}}

Comment: 1. What is the structure of you JSON? please, provide an example. 2. How this JSON will be available to your code (passed as a parameter, loaded from somewhere, injected by the container?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it, I came to the conclusion that BootsFaces should not support this feature. So we won't implement it in BootsFaces. That's because Json is an incredibly flexible format. `b:selectOneMenu` only supports simple lists consisting of key-value-pairs. Obviously, there's a mismatch between the flexible Json format and the data structure required by `b:selectOneMenu`. Mind you: what should we do with the extra fields `date` and `comment` of your example?

However, you can convert the Json format to the key-value-pairs yourself. A simple approach would be to implement such a converter in the `getData()` method of your example. In a real-world example you'd probably use a caching approach because `getData()` is called fairly often.